# iOS app crashes with apple test

Tags: ios, swift, crash, app-store-connect

I submitted an app for review and it's crashes with apple testers. 
however it's run perfectly on company's iPhone but it's crashes on iPad.
[Crashlog](http://a1084.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple128/v4/9d/2b/3a/9d2b3aba-d246-a9ae-976d-32a208942d7d/attachment-4666096797802184540crashlog-4CD604F5-F1BB-43C3-8ED5-EC4C3E14D32E.txt?downloadKey3=1519397324_6af156074b5e3e87b456baffe7be25f3)

*note my app is reading the location from SIM card

```
func renderFlag(){

    let country = Utility.getObjectFromUserDefaults(fromKey: "userCountry") as? Country
    if country?.countryID != "" && country?.countryID != nil
    {
        print("step1")
        Utility.downloadImageForButton(imageURL: (country?.countryFlag)!, button: self.countryBtn)
    }
    else
    {
        print("step2")
        let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo();
        let isoCountryCode = networkInfo.subscriberCellularProvider?.isoCountryCode
        var noCountries = 0
        print("step3")
        for c in self.countries
        {
            noCountries += 1
            print(c.toJSON())
            var countryISO = c.iso_code!
            var phoneCountryCode = networkInfo.subscriberCellularProvider?.isoCountryCode!

            //if(countryISO == nil ){ countryISO =  "jo"} //for chosing JO by default
            //if(phoneCountryCode == nil ){ phoneCountryCode = "jo"} //for chosing JO by default

            print("step3.5" + "\(countryISO)" + "\(phoneCountryCode)")
           // print("phoneCountryCode \(phoneCountryCode!)")
             print("step4")
            if phoneCountryCode == countryISO || phoneCountryCode == countryISO.capitalized
            {

                print("phoneCountryCode \(phoneCountryCode!) countryISO \(countryISO)")
                 print("step5")
                let imagePath = c.countryFlag!
                Utility.downloadImageForButton(imageURL: imagePath, button: self.countryBtn)
                Utility.saveObjectInUserDefaults(objectValue: c, forKey: "userCountry")
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It is not too clever to post stacktrace containing your application information :) just sayin'

Comment: @DominikBucher yes thank you, but I can't read it so I need some one to help me, thank you for you advice

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have supplied i'm guessing it's because the forced unwrapped variables. Apple's review team probably is operating with either iPad's without sim card or iPad's with no cellular capabilities at all (or both).

My guess is it crashes on this line (purely speculative, because you also force unwrap variables earlier on):

```
var phoneCountryCode = networkInfo.subscriberCellularProvider?.isoCountryCode!
```

You should give a default value using the `??` operator.

Also get rid of these unwrappings using, for example, the `??` operator:

```
Utility.downloadImageForButton(imageURL: (country?.countryFlag)!, button: self.countryBtn)

var countryISO = c.iso_code!

print("phoneCountryCode \(phoneCountryCode!) countryISO \(countryISO)")

let imagePath = c.countryFlag!
```

When you program in good alternatives the application should no longer crash, probably also not work like you want it to, but that's why you have to pick the right default values.